# Se puede agregar una interface de autocad en un sitio web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, aplicación-web

Desarrollo la idea.
Estoy creando un sitio web en HTML, CSS y un poco de Javascript
Ahora mi duda surge de la siguiente idea.
Esta empresa tiene unas piedras + o - 4mt por 2mt, un rectangulo
de las cuales tengo fotos que he arreglado con photoshop para que tengan el diametro exacto en metros.
ahi alguna manera de crear una interface en la cual este la foto de la piedra el cliente pueda dibujar el tamano que necesita dentro del rango de esa piedra y mandarme esa foto a una base de datos obviamente con los datos del cliente.
hagan de cuenta tener una especia de app dentro de la web que me tome medidas dentro de la foto de la piedra.
Si me he explicado bien, alguien puede darme una luz con esta idea?
De ante mano gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Autocad no es un software gratuito lo menciono por que si quieres algo relacionado a ello lo deberás de pagar, por otro lado si andas en ambiente web ¿por que no usar canvas?

Comment: Por cierto tu pregunta es amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generará su cierre